# Java - rotate image in place

Tags: java, rotation, image-rotation

I have a tank cannon layer that should rotate toward the mouse position, which I have done with the following code:

```
double theta = Math.atan2(point.getY() - center.getY(), point.getX() - center.getX());
```

then I rotate the graphics object's transform accordingly. This works, but the cannon rotates around the cannon's center. I want the cannon's base to stay in position when the rotation happens. I've tried many different positions to rotate around, but I can't get one that will keep its base in position. I think that I must translate the graphics object after rotation to where the cannon's base should be, but I don't know how. My cannon with both layers: [image]

As you can see, the base (the light green part) must stay in it's position. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Assuming that the "tank" and "cannon" are separate entities, you can specify the anchor point around which the image should be rotated

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but have you tried `Math.atan2(point.getY(), point.getX());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, assuming that the turret and base are separate images, and the turret isn't the same size as the tank (cause then it becomes complicated....more then it actually is :P)

You can use a `AffineTransform` and compound the transformations...

```
    // This is the x/y position of the top, at the top/left point,
    // I've placed it at the center of my screen, but you get the idea
    double x = (getWidth() - base.getWidth()) / 2d;
    double y = (getHeight() - base.getHeight()) / 2d;

    // Translate the location to the x/y, this makes the top/left 0x0...
    // much easier to deal with...
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
    g2d.setTransform(at);
    // Draw the base...
    g2d.drawImage(base, 0, 0, this);

    // Offset the turret, in my testing, this was 8x8 from the bases
    // top/left
    at.translate(8, 8);
    if (targetPoint != null) {
        // Calculate the delta between the mouse and the center point
        // of the turret, this is in screen coordinates and not
        // translated coordinates
        double deltaX = (x + 8) - targetPoint.x;
        double deltaY = (y + 8) - targetPoint.y;

        // Calculate the rotation required to point at the mouse
        // Had to apply an offset to allow for the default orientation
        // of the tank...
        double rotation = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) + Math.toRadians(180d);
        // Rotate around the anchor point of the turret
        // Remember, we've translated so the top/left (0x0) is now the
        // turrets default position
        at.rotate(rotation, 4, 4);
    }
    // Transform the Graphics context
    g2d.setTransform(at);
    // Paint the turret
    g2d.drawImage(turret, 0, 0, this);
}
g2d.dispose();
```

And because I went to effort...

My assets...

[image: Base][image: Turret]

[image: Tank]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FollowMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FollowMe();
    }

    public FollowMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Point targetPoint;
        private BufferedImage turret;
        private BufferedImage base;

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    targetPoint = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }

            });
            try {
                base = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Base.png"));
                turret = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Turret.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
            g.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
            if (base != null) {
                double x = (getWidth() - base.getWidth()) / 2d;
                double y = (getHeight() - base.getHeight()) / 2d;
                // Test line from center of tank to mouse poisition
                if (targetPoint != null) {
                    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double((x + 12), (y + 12), targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y));
                }
                AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
                g2d.setTransform(at);
                g2d.drawImage(base, 0, 0, this);
                at.translate(8, 8);
                if (targetPoint != null) {
                    double deltaX = (x + 8) - targetPoint.x;
                    double deltaY = (y + 8) - targetPoint.y;

                    double rotation = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) + Math.toRadians(180d);
                    at.rotate(rotation, 4, 4);
                }
                g2d.setTransform(at);
                g2d.drawImage(turret, 0, 0, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) for more details

Comment: Wow, you wrote a small game within a few minutes with fancy graphics. You are a really _mad_ programmer :-)

Comment: @chris Actually did something like this yesterday, but had more layers to it :P

Answer (score 1):

Your formula just shows how you calculate the angle - your question seems to be 'how to rotate an image around a specified point'. For that i would recommend using `AffineTransform`s (matrices math). A good point to start is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html.

Some sample code:

```
Graphics2D g; //<- you should have this in your code somewhere
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(); 
at.rotate(theta, centerX, centerY); //<- your question: rotate around specified point
g.setTransform(at); //<- tell the graphics to transform before painting
g.drawImage(...); //<- draws transformed image
```

If you look deeper into `AffineTransform.rotate(...)` you see that at first a translation is made, then the rotation. The third transform is a translation with the negative x/y values.

This is the good old code from sun:

```
public void rotate(double theta, double anchorx, double anchory) {
    // REMIND: Simple for now - optimize later
    translate(anchorx, anchory);
    rotate(theta);
    translate(-anchorx, -anchory);
}
```

Working with matrices is pretty powerful as you can combine translations, rotations, shear, mirror and whatnot. Not only in 2d but also in 3d. Maybe your tank will someday leave the flat world and become a volume model...