# Is there a way I can rotate one object and not both of them?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am working on a project that has a GUI and tanks that move. While tanks move fine, I am not able to figure out how to move/rotate them individually. I also need to clean my code as I feel I have a lot of extra stuff going on.

Here is some code, and here's what I tried.

I have four classes. *Missiles*, *Tanks*, and *Board*. I am calling keylisteners in the *Tank* class. Should I do that in the doDrawing method? The doDrawing method is in the *Board* class.

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g)
{
    final double rads = Math.toRadians(120);
    final double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads));
    final double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
    final int w = (int) Math.floor(tank1.getX() * cos + tank1.getX() * sin);
    final int h = (int) Math.floor(tank1.getY() * cos + tank1.getY() * sin);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(w, h);
    g2d.rotate(rot, tank1.getX(), tank1.getY());

    AffineTransform backup = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();

    g2d.setTransform(backup);
    //g2d.drawImage(tank1.getImage(), tank1.getX(), tank1.getY(), this);

    trans.setToIdentity();
    trans.rotate(rot, h, w);
    trans.translate(h, w);
    trans.setTransform(backup);

    g2d.drawImage(tank1.getImage(), tank1.getX(), tank1.getY(), this);

    //g2d.drawImage(tank1.getImage(), tank1.getX(), tank1.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(tank2.getImage(), tank2.getX(), tank2.getY(), this);

    List<Missile> missiles = tank1.getMissiles();

    for (Missile missile : missiles)
    {
        //trans.rotate(Math.toRadians(rads), w/2, h/2);
        g2d.drawImage(missile.getImage(), missile.getX(), missile.getY() - 7, this);
        //g2d.rotate(rot, missile.getX(), missile.getY() - 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Re *"Missiles, Tanks, and Board"*: What is the fourth class?

Comment: Missile and Tank classes extend Tankset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, just looking at...

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g)
{
    //...
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(w, h);
    g2d.rotate(rot, tank1.getX(), tank1.getY());

    AffineTransform backup = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
    
    g2d.setTransform(backup);
    //g2d.drawImage(tank1.getImage(), tank1.getX(), tank1.getY(), this);
    
    trans.setToIdentity();
    trans.rotate(rot, h, w); 
    trans.translate(h,w);
    trans.setTransform(backup);
                
    g2d.drawImage(tank1.getImage(), tank1.getX(), tank1.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(tank2.getImage(), tank2.getX(), tank2.getY(), this);
    //...
}
```

It's immediately obvious that you're applying a transformation to the `Graphics` context which is never undone, so everything painted after it will have the same transformation applied to it.

The first thing you need to do is break the paint logic down so that it can paint a single entity.

The second thing you need to do is create a copy of the `Graphics` context before you make any modifications to it, this will prevent the parent copy from carrying those modifications forward which will then be compounded with future modifications.

Maybe something like...

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    // Because I don't trust anybody
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    drawTank(tank1, g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    drawTank(tank2, g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
}

private void drawTank(Tank tank, Graphics2D g) {
    final double rads = Math.toRadians(120);
    final double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads));
    final double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
    final int w = (int) Math.floor(tank.getX() * cos + tank.getX() * sin);
    final int h = (int) Math.floor(tank.getY() * cos + tank.getY() * sin);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.translate(w, h);
    // `rot` should be derived from the tank ... no idea where this is
    g2d.translate(tank.getX(), tank.getY());
    // Origin has now been translated to the tanks position
    g2d.rotate(rot, 0, 0);
    g2d.drawImage(tank.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
    
    // We no longer to need to keep these resources
    g2d.dispose();
    // Create a new "clean" copy
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    // I don't know if it's needed, but I would, personally, calculate
    // any required rotation again, but that's me
    List<Missile> missiles = tank1.getMissiles();
    for (Missile missile : missiles) {
        g2d.drawImage(missile.getImage(), missile.getX(), missile.getY() - 7, this);
    }
}
```

For example, see:

- [Java - rotate image in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129385/java-rotate-image-in-place/31130133#31130133)
- [How to move paint graphics along slope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411743/how-to-move-paint-graphics-along-slope/72412859#72412859)

Comment: Maybe the tank rotates by having different images. The global transformation might be to rotate the map?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Maybe we don't have enough information available to fully understand the problem and much of what is been suggest is speculation - but in the context of the question, if the OP wants to rotate the tanks individual, this is the way to get started.  They could apply compounding rotations if they want to rotate the board AND the tank, but that is beyond the available scope

Comment: Thank you, the tanks rotate together but don't move together. How can I stop them from rotating together?

Comment: @Aytida As has been stated by me and Hovercraft, the rotation information needs to be isolated to each tank instance. You then need to isolate the rendering workflow per tank and make sure they have the "base" graphics context and that they create a copy before applying new transformations

Comment: @Aytida And also look at the comment `// rot should be derived from the tank ... no idea where this is`

Comment: It's in the tank class. But thanks, I understood what you're saying. And similarly, have a different class/instance for missiles?

Comment: @Aytida I would think that the projectiles need to be seperate entities, as their state needs to be managed individually.  You might find that the missile needs to know about how fired it.  In my example, I removed the tank rotation before drawing the projectiles, as you can do some basic trig to determine what direction they should facing based on source and target points

Answer (score 2):

## Recommendations:

1. Keep logic separate from display using a model-view code structure
2. In keeping with that, create a Tank *logical* class, one that knows its own position *and its own orientation* (or angle), and save your `java.util.List<Tank>` in the program's model.
3. Change the Tank position and orientation within a listener.
4. Use the View classes (the GUI classes) only to a) draw the state of the class's model and b) get input from the user.
5. Side recommendation: If this is Swing, avoid KeyListeners and instead use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
6. You can use separate affine transforms for each tank

Answer (score 1):

If your tanks move/rotate synchronously I guess the reason is that they all receive the same key events and react the same way.

Put the keylistener (or even better KeyBindings as suggested in another answer) into your Board class. The listener will check which key is pressed/released and give the correct tank the command to move or turn or whatever. This way you can make one tank react to WASD, while the other reacts on up/down/left/right.

The methods in the tank class however do not react to key events but could be named like forward, backward, turnleft, turnright.

The doDrawing method should do exactly as it's name suggests: just perform the drawing. This can happen any amount of times to get good screen refresh rates or redraw the board after another window no longer hides your game.

Comment: do you suggest that I should have a list of tanks? and then allot commands accordingly. Because eventually I want to make this into a multiplayer game.

Comment: KeyListener? Please no

Comment: If you want a multiplayer game, then it depends how you receive your events: Some player at the console may use a joystick, another the mouse and maybe two more the keyboard. You could also receive events to move the tank via network sockets. Use listeners as you feel the need for it. But each of them needs to know which tank to control. So far I was assuming there are only two.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Hovercraft's comment is based on `KeyListener` been a poor choice for monitoring keyboard events and that there are better options available in Swing.  Too many questions abound about "why does my `KeyListener` not work", when a solution exists which will fix it.  Key bindings also support a better concept of a decouple input, so you have keyboard, joy stick, controller or what ever acting as the input and the workflow can be easily decoupled to support them - just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do not object - instead I edited my post. My response was related to Aytida's comment about a multiplayer game.